# grep a single awk column

Tags: awk

Here is my sample data:

```
XYZ Domain|agent756|allegr8732|2022-01-12 15:36:24.0|0|{"username":"sample_usernme","login":"jack777","groups":[],"emailAddress":"sample@sample.com","company":null,"phone":null,"bindedKeys":["sample_usernme"],"owner":null,"expirationDate":null,"uploadsQuota":null,"downloadsQuota":null,"transfersQuota":null,"maxTransferRateBytesPerSecond":null,"resources":[{"type":"VirtualRemoteFileDescriptor","path":"","accessPermissions":{"fileDownloadingAllowed":true,"fileUploadingAllowed":true,"fileOverwritingAllowed":true,"fileDeletionAllowed":true,"fileAppendingAllowed":true,"fileListingAllowed":true,"fileRenamingAllowed":true,"directoriesListingAllowed":true,"directoryMakingAllowed":true,"directoryDeletionAllowed":true,"subdirectoriesBrowsingAllowed":true},"secured":false,"denied":false,"indexable":false,"name":"ref_proxy"}],"administration":null,"secured":false,"enabled":true,"passwordChangingAllowed":true,"emailFileTransferAllowed":true,"usePhoneAuthentication":false,"ignorePasswordAgingRules":false,"passwordResetRequired":false,"loginRedirection":{"type":"DirectoryRedirection","directory":""},"lastLoginDate":null,"ipAccessVerifier":{"type":"NullVerifier"},"maxUploadsPerSession":null,"maxDownloadsPerSession":null,"webPublicKeyAuthenticationAvailable":true,"webOpenPgpEncryptionAvailable":true,"webQuotasAvailable":true,"webContactsAvailable":true,"webAdHocActivityAvailable":true,"webDropZonesAvailable":true,"webAccountLinkAvailable":true,"webPersonalInformationAvailable":true,"passwordExpirationNotification":null,"otpSharedSecret":null,"notes":"","options":{},"tags":[],"creationDate":1602502466555,"version":3,"passwordHash":"","expired":false,"passwordDate":1602501463354,"passwordHistory":[],"memberOfAnyGroup":false}
```

I would like to get result:

```
myh.com|XYZ Domain|agent756|allegr8732|0|true
```

true- it is a result of regex: `(?<="enabled":).*?(?=,")`

to do this I tried something like this:

```
cat users.txt | awk -F"|" -vhostname="$(hostname)" '{ print hostname"|"$1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$5"|"... }'
```

How can I print in addition $6 using sample regex to get value "true" ?

Comment: Where does "myh.com" appear?

Comment: "myh.com" is my sample local hostname : from ```-vhostname="$(hostname)```

Comment: Something like this: `dat=$(regex); awk -v var="${dat}" '{ ..., var }' users.txt`

Comment: Rather than concatenating fields with `"|"`, you could set OFS: `awk ... '{print hostname, $1, $2 , ... }' OFS=\|`.

Comment: UUOC: instead of `cat users.txt | awk ...`, use `awk ... users.txt` or `< users.txt awk ...`

Answer (score 1):

Parse JSON data with a JSON parser:

```sh
data='XYZ Domain|agent756|allegr8732|2022-01-12 15:36:24.0|0|{"username":"sample_usernme","login":"jack777","groups":[],"emailAddress":"sample@sample.com","company":null,"phone":null,"bindedKeys":["sample_usernme"],"owner":null,"expirationDate":null,"uploadsQuota":null,"downloadsQuota":null,"transfersQuota":null,"maxTransferRateBytesPerSecond":null,"resources":[{"type":"VirtualRemoteFileDescriptor","path":"","accessPermissions":{"fileDownloadingAllowed":true,"fileUploadingAllowed":true,"fileOverwritingAllowed":true,"fileDeletionAllowed":true,"fileAppendingAllowed":true,"fileListingAllowed":true,"fileRenamingAllowed":true,"directoriesListingAllowed":true,"directoryMakingAllowed":true,"directoryDeletionAllowed":true,"subdirectoriesBrowsingAllowed":true},"secured":false,"denied":false,"indexable":false,"name":"ref_proxy"}],"administration":null,"secured":false,"enabled":true,"passwordChangingAllowed":true,"emailFileTransferAllowed":true,"usePhoneAuthentication":false,"ignorePasswordAgingRules":false,"passwordResetRequired":false,"loginRedirection":{"type":"DirectoryRedirection","directory":""},"lastLoginDate":null,"ipAccessVerifier":{"type":"NullVerifier"},"maxUploadsPerSession":null,"maxDownloadsPerSession":null,"webPublicKeyAuthenticationAvailable":true,"webOpenPgpEncryptionAvailable":true,"webQuotasAvailable":true,"webContactsAvailable":true,"webAdHocActivityAvailable":true,"webDropZonesAvailable":true,"webAccountLinkAvailable":true,"webPersonalInformationAvailable":true,"passwordExpirationNotification":null,"otpSharedSecret":null,"notes":"","options":{},"tags":[],"creationDate":1602502466555,"version":3,"passwordHash":"","expired":false,"passwordDate":1602501463354,"passwordHistory":[],"memberOfAnyGroup":false}'

IFS='|' read -ra fields <<<"$data"
wanted=(
    "$(hostname)"
    "${fields[@]:0:3}"
    "${fields[4]}"
    "$(jq -r .enabled <<<"${fields[5]}")"
)

(IFS='|'; echo "${wanted[*]}")
```

```
myh.com|XYZ Domain|agent756|allegr8732|0|true
```

---

Actually, the json data might contain the pipe character: this is better

```sh
while IFS='|' read -r a b c d e f; do
  printf '%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n' "$(hostname)" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$e" "$(jq -r .enabled <<<"$f")"
done < users.txt
```

---

Other languages have JSON libraries included. For example, ruby

```sh
ruby -rjson -e '
  File.new(ARGV.shift).each do |line|
    f = line.split /[|]/, 6
    json = JSON.parse f[5]
    wanted = [%x(hostname).chomp, f[0], f[1], f[2], f[4], json["enabled"]]
    puts wanted.join "|"
  end
' users.txt
```